# sort array of objects by surname java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am stuck on this following piece of code I have been trying to use a bubble sort to sort the array of objects by surname then print it out. where Am i going wrong and how can i print it out? here is my code

```
for(int i = 1; i < clipArray.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < clipArray.length; j++) {
        if(((clipArray[j].getSurname()).compareToIgnoreCase((clipArray[j+1].getSurname()))) {
            Clip temp = clipArray[j];
            clipArray[j] = clipArray[j+1];
            clipArray[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

problem: required boolean, found int

Comment: What is the issue you are facing in printing the array?

Comment: First problem I see is that clipArray[j+1] will index out of the array (see your second loop)

Comment: Tell us *what's* going wrong first. Provide some input and output. [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc.

Comment: how can I fix this sort?

Comment: it says required boolean, found int

Comment: This should help. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: That's because `compareToIgnoreCase` returns an `int`. You need to compare this result with another integer like `< 0`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You should post that as the answer

Comment: i thought this compares the strings, could you give an example of a working sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`String#compareToIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) returns an `int` and you require a `boolean` result for `if` statement. From its javadoc:

> **Returns**
>
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the specified String is greater than, equal to, or less than this String, ignoring case considerations

So, compare the result of this method with another number according to the definition.

```
if (clipArray[j].getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(clipArray[j+1].getSurname()) < 0) {
    //...
}
```

Also, you have another error in your `for` loop declarations. They should be like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < clipArray.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < clipArray.length - 1; j++) { //spot the difference
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much i understand now! last problem i'm having is that I can't print the sorted array

Comment: System.out.println(clipArray[].getSurname());

Comment: After you are done sorting the array, create a new loop and print out each surname.

Answer (score 2):

Your Comparator class

```
class SampleComparator implements Comparator<Clip> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Clip o1, Clip o2) {

           return o1.getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getSurname());
   }
}
```

Your sorting here

```
Arrays.sort(clipArray,new SampleComparator());
```

Comment: -1: This is a homework exercise. Using `Arrays#sort` is obviously not an answer.

Comment: This isn't the issue.  Why are people up-voting this?

Answer (score 2):

The error is because

> compareToIgnoreCase return int values not boolean.
>
> returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the
>   specified String is greater than, equal to, or less than this String,
>   ignoring case considerations.

If only takes boolean.

Comment: so how can i fix it so that it is comparing the strings and i can then sort it alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your clipArray is filled with objects that support the `getSurname()`-method.

The method `compareToIgnoreCase` returns an int, so you should compare it with a value in your `if`-statement, like

```
if(foo.compareTo(bar) > 0)
```